# Bareos Autochanger not pulling tape

Tags: backup, tapedrive, bareos, autoloader

I've taken over a configuration of Bareos on Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie). Its a fresh install, using both file and Autochanger storage.

Everything looks correct and `bconsole` will talk with the changer (I can move, mount, unmout, label tapes etc.).

Problem:
The backups will write to the autochanger's drive - but ONLY if the tape is manually mounted. If the drive is empty, the backup job will not pull a tape into the drive.  It just stays queued indefinitely. If I move the tape to the dirve (even after the job is started) it runs fine.

The tapes are barcoded and labeled.

See pertinent config below:

**bareos-dir:**

```
Director {                            # define myself
  Name = pxxx-dir
  QueryFile = "/usr/lib/bareos/scripts/query.sql"
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 10
  Password = "rXjxxx"         # Console password
  Messages = Daemon
  Auditing = yes
}

Storage {
  Name = Tape
  Address = pxxx
  Password = "e9cxxx"
  Device = FlexStor_II
  Media Type = LTO-7
  Autochanger = yes
}

FileSet {
  Name = "SelfTestHuge"
  Description = "Huge fileset"
  Include {
    Options {
      Signature = MD5 # calculate md5 checksum per file
    }
    File = "/mnt/45GB-Directory"
  }
}

Job {
  Name = "BackupSelfTestTapeHuge"
  FileSet = "SelfTestHuge"
  JobDefs = "TestTapeHuge"
}

JobDefs {
  Name = "TestTapeHuge"
  Type = Backup
  Level = Full
  Client = pxxx-fd
  FileSet = "SelfTestHuge"
  Storage = Tape
  Messages = Standard
  Pool = Full
  Priority = 10
  Write Bootstrap = "/var/lib/bareos/%c.bsr"
  Full Backup Pool = Full
  Differential Backup Pool = Differential
  Incremental Backup Pool = Incremental
}
```

**bareos-sd:**

```
Storage {
  Name = pxxx-sd
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 20
}

Director {
  Name = pxxx-dir
  Password = "e9cxxx"
  Description = "Director, permitted to contact this storage daemon."
}

Autochanger {
  Name = "FlexStor_II"
  Changer Device = /dev/tape/by-id/scsi-1BDT_FlexStor_II_00MX64200449_LL0
  Device = ULTRIUM-HH7-0
  Device = ULTRIUM-HH7-1
  Changer Command = "/usr/lib/bareos/scripts/mtx-changer %c %o %S %a %d"
}

Device {
    Name = "ULTRIUM-HH7-0"
    DeviceType = tape
    DriveIndex = 0
    ArchiveDevice = /dev/tape/by-id/scsi-35000e1116b5b8001-nst
    MediaType = LTO-7
    Check Labels = yes
    AutoChanger = yes
    AutomaticMount = yes
    MaximumFileSize = 500GB
    AlwaysOpen = yes
}

Device {
    Name = "ULTRIUM-HH7-1"
    DeviceType = tape
    DriveIndex = 1
    ArchiveDevice = /dev/tape/by-id/scsi-35000e1116b5b8004-nst
    MediaType = LTO-7
    Check Labels = yes
    AutoChanger = yes
    AutomaticMount = yes
    MaximumFileSize = 500GB
    AlwaysOpen = yes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mailing list figured it out.

I had to edit the devices (tape Ultirum drives).

First comment out...

```
# Check Labels = yes
```

and add the following...

```
Autoselect = yes
RemovableMedia = yes
```